# Docker's applicability

Tags: docker

Right now i have a bunch of servers with just bare metal installed O/S and software.
Main components are nginx, php-fpm, ffmpeg and a few other tools for video encoding. Each hour via cron server grabs video converting tasks, does them and places ready video to a folder which. Nginx then streams these videos.

The problem is i'm very tired of syncing config files, updating software, disitrubing software which  was compiled from sources, etc.

So i guess first of all i need to seperate video files and all the software i have. Video files will be still kept on a server itself. For a software container i could use OpenVZ. So if i need to update the software i just update my OpenVZ template and copy this image + vzctl destroy + vzctl create on each server. But i do not see good ways of mounting directory with video files to OpenVZ container. I thins NFS, iSCSI are bad in my case as there should be better ways.

That's why i thought maybe Docker is a good solution. As far as i know it allows to mount external resources to it using just a cli call. So i just build a docker container with nginx + fpm + video tools in it, distribute it among my servers and attach local storage with files.

Please write you opinion. Is it a good way of using docker or my solution is something else?

Comment: If you do consider the docker route, also take a look at CoreOS as your base OS on the servers which uses docker.

Comment: I do not know really if CoreOS is a good solution. As i known CoreOS does not have any packet manager so it's impossible to install extra software on it. 
I planned to use rsync to sync video files between master-slave server pair and if rsync does not exists in coreos by default ... Another docker container with just rsync?

Comment: fwiw, you can certainly mount host directories into OpenVZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer this without more information. But here are some ideas for a Docker world.

First, I'd try to think about the Docker images and containers more as applications than VMs. Separately manage the host infrastructure from Docker containers. It might be perfectly applicable to run Puppet or Chef on the hosts to manage your Docker containers and dependencies. Once you get to a fully containerized world you get to really simplify your hosts by running a platform like CoreOS. But I probably wouldn't start with CoreOS if you are just getting into Docker.

Separate your applications and video files (which you have already mentioned). Build 'data only' containers that persist video files on the hosts. I like to use the `tianon/true` Docker image for this. Run the image with a volume that can be persisted:

```
docker run -d --name videodata -v /videodata tianon/true
```

It sounds like you would next have at least one other image for your nginx, PHP-FPM, and ffmpeg container. Though, I would likely try separating these components out into separate images. You might have a PHP-FPM container that runs your code and exposes a port or socket for nginx to use for reverse proxying. This container would also use `--volumes-from` to mount the persistent `/videodata` folder.

```
docker run -d --name application --volumes-from videodata myorg/myappimage
```

Then you may have an nginx image which utilizes Docker link DNS to hit PHP-FPM:

```
docker run -d --name web -p 80:80 --link application:phpfpm myorg/mynginximage
```

In the nginx configuration you can directly hit the DNS name `phpfpm` to resolve the IP address of the application container.

The next expansion of this would be getting more into service discovery. You might replace the nginx image with an appliance like https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy to automatically add and remove application containers as they come and go.

Once you start getting into a multi-host Docker world, tools and concepts like service directories (https://github.com/progrium/docker-consul), ambassadors (https://github.com/progrium/ambassadord), dynamic service registration in directories (https://github.com/progrium/registrator), and load balancing (https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-haproxy) will be more interesting.

So, to answer your question, I think you have valid use cases for Docker. But I don't think mixing OpenVZ and Docker is really a good idea. You probably want one or the other.

Comment: I wasn't going to do a mix. 
The only ideological problem i have is a ffmpeg container. Starting a container i need to specify a programm to run. Currently i have script which grabs URL with convert tasks via cron. What is the best way to containerize it?

Comment: Could this container only run `ffmpeg` and the script on a cron? The container could be just cron, ffmpeg, and your script and the default CMD you start is the cron daemon in foreground. Another alternative would be to schedule the container to run on a cronjob on the host so that each run of the container would run your script and ffmpeg. This really depends on where you would like to keep the scheduling logic.

Comment: I thought that cron runs by default inside a docker container. If not it's really inreresting how does the session directory gets cleaned if it's an Apache container. Usually it's a cron job with find+rm.
Or it does run, but in a background?

Comment: This really depends on what you are installing in the image and expecting to run. For example, the `ubuntu` image does have cron installed, but it does not start up by default. You could start it up with something like `CMD cron`. It runs in the background so in theory, you could launch it before any other daemon you expect to be in the foreground as well: `CMD cron && mydaemon -D`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for configuration management tools like Puppet, Chef, Ansible or CFEngine.

With these tools you make configuration templates, which can then be applied to multiple servers.

Basically, when you have done your configuration system in the configuration management system, you run a single command on all servers, which then applies the configuration.

Comment: I thought about that but i think it's not really the best choice. Puppet/Chef are for more complex/enterprise scenarios than mine one. I have some software which i build from sources so it's library dependent. In case of different server O/S i'll get into troubles with puppet. Containers allow to bypass these problems.

Comment: @user2660496 And what happens when you need to install updates? You have to build your whole container again. With my Puppet environment I just run `mco package update nginx` and every server I manage gets the update.

Comment: And hope like hell nothing gets broken during the package update.  With the container approach like docker, you can roll back the entire container to the previous one.

Comment: Exactly. That's why i thought about docker or something.
With docker i can rebuild software within a container, test it if it's working and send it to all nodes.
With puppet i should blindly write an ./configure && make && make install script and then hope that installation will finish successfully.

Comment: @Matt That's why we test first.

Comment: Where do you test? On one of the machines? If yes then it's not a suprprise if setup fails somewhere on another machine which maybe has a little bit different set of packages.